# Chrome vs. IE, etc. on Windows Azure Using Postbacks

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, jquery, azure

I've posted a similar question previously but got no responses so I've tried to make it much more specific (I've been able to do this after a LOAD of testing). I wouldn't keep pushing but this is a show-stopper and is driving me crazy.

I have an MVC3 application. In it I have a Test controller containing the following two methods:

```
public ActionResult Test2()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Test2Get()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(270000);
    var x = "Author = x";
    return Json(x,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The Test2 view is as follows:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test2";
}

<h2>Test2</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.lp-web.net/Test/Test2Get',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (result) { alert('success'); }
        });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see the Test2 View simply executes a callback "on load" to a method that sleeps for 4.5 minutes then returns some JSON.

When run locally in VS through the Azure emulator this works fine on all browsers. If I construct a non-Azure version and deploy to a hosted server then this works fine in all browsers. By "works" I mean the alert with the 'success' message is displayed.

HOWEVER, when deployed to Windows Azure this only works if I use Chrome. Otherwise the alert never appears.

There are other tidbits: e.g. if the sleep duration is set to 4 minutes or less all browsers work, even when the app is deployed to Azure. But I really don't know what relevance that has.

I was hoping someone had an idea where I could look. If anyone wants to try this themselves you can just go to http://www.lp-web.net, click the "Test2" action link and wait 4.5 minutes. I'd be curious to see if it's "just me".

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the connection is timing out at the load balancer. The load balancer timeout has a default of four minutes (used to be one) after which point the connection is reset.

That doesn't completely explain why Chrome works; however, [the bottom of this thread observes](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/89b283f0-dfca-49a7-99fe-c3b73d77ff6d) there was similar behavior that affected IE and Firefox (which by naming them explicitly might connote it not happening on Chrome?)

For more context on the load balancer implication and how you might remedy, check out [Windows Azure Load Balancer Timeout Details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/11/12/windows-azure-load-balancer-timeout-details.aspx).

Comment: You know, I actually Googled something like ASP.NET MVC Azure four minute error, or something like that, with no success, because I noticed the problem occurred PRECISELY (even a millisecond) over four minutes. Thanks very much, I'll check out the thread you linked to. My psyche NEEDS to find out what's happening; as you point out, the fact that Chrome works fine is what really is throwing a monkey wrench into this. Of course in the meantime I'll prepare a non-Azure version of my app. :)

Comment: Just to follow up: perhaps Chrome works because (as has been speculated) it sends keep-alive packets more frequently or for longer periods. Again, I don't know if this is true or, even if it is, if it would explain what's happening, but I'll try using ServicePointManager or IE registry entries to test.

Comment: you could install a network monitor on the Azure role instance and then RDP into it as you hit the public URL through the end point.  A bit of set up there, but may be a quick way to soothe the psyche :)

Comment: Jim, appreciate the advice, your suggestion seems a bit above my pay grade but I'm a fairly clever fellow. At this point, I've spent endless hours trying to solve this with AsyncControllers. I also set up a timed JS callback to "ping" a method in the same controller at 30 second intervals, still no go. I've also tried using System.Net.ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive(true,500000,500000). Nothing. I'm angry, I'm missing something obvious. I'm quickly realizing that my only option is to move off Azure. I need to execute processes that take longer than 4 minutes and I can't require Chrome.